# lyx: editing bibliography options AFTER bibliography is loaded

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, sorting, bibliographystyle

I am writing my PhD thesis in LyX 2.3.7 and have been trying to get my bibliography (built in JabRef) in the format i want but i can't seem to manage. The problems are the following:

1: I do not manage to fix the max number of authors in the bibliography, not even using the maxbibnames option.

2: I do not manage to make the bibliography items be displayed in order of citation. They seem to keep the order in which they are written in the bib file. I tried all possible style combinations, adding the \renewcommand\bibliographystyle{unsrt} and other options but it never gets solved.

At the moment i do not have any preamble loaded (all the previous attempts failed), and the options i am using for the bibliography throught the LyX interface are the following

[image]

and the result i get at the moment is of this type

[image]

I would like to (if possible) keep the bibliography and references to be displayed with the numbers and have them in order of citation in the main text.

I know that LyX loads the biblatex package after the preamble, and with the "\AtBeginDocument" command you can in principle sneak code after the loading, but nothing seems to work.

I would be extremely grateful if anyone managed to help me with this. Thanks a lot!

EDIT 1: here is the Tex intermediate file if i ask LyX to export to PDFLatex

```
 %% LyX 2.3.7 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=4cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm,headheight=1cm,headsep=1cm,footskip=2cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.



\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\string"bibliography test.bib\string"}
\begin{document}
\title{\onehalfspacing{}test thesis}

\maketitle
here is the first and second citation \citep{FrigeriAgterbergMilatEtAl,MiyadaiKikuchiKondoEtAl}
here is the third citation \citep{TsurutaMitoKousakaEtAl} here is
the fourth citation \citep{Miranda2021}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

with this result

[image]

EDIT 2: Here is the link for the Lyx file and the bibliography
https://file.io/7NNQwtyxa9RM

Comment: Can you show the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: Can you try with `natbib,sorting=none` in the "Options:" field? (The goal would be to have `\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,natbib,sorting=none]{biblatex}` in the intermediate .tex file)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz just tried, the result i get by compiling through lyx is the same as the one i get in the second picture. Some online guides have shown that the Options part in the bibliography interface for lyx doesn't work that well.

Comment: I'm not a lyx user, so I can help further. That was just how the code should look like from the tex side.

Comment: I don't understand the LaTeX part of this at all, but if you post the .lyx file, I can take a look at how to make it so we get the options @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz mentioned.

Comment: @scottkosty just posted them, hope they can help

Comment: I tried Sam Carter's suggestion and it works for me (at least for the order of citations). Just to make sure, here is what I did: 1. I opened your .lyx file. 2. I went to the "Bibliography" tab (the one that is shown in your screenshot in the post). 3. I pasted "sorting=none" into the options there. 4. I clicked on "OK". Then I compiled and the references look as you prefer.